# See which files are forming a specific php page?

Tags: php

Does anyone know of a web development toll which will tell me what physical php files are being pulled together to form the page?

Example.

I have `index.php` which is made up of `header.php` `sidebar.php` `news.php` and `footer.php`. Is there a tool available that'll inform me that `index.php` is formed by these pages when I access it?

Comment: You'd like to find this out for any webpage, or your webpage?

Comment: Any webpage would be what I want

Comment: this is impossible. You can't even be sure that the webpage is running on PHP when not having real access to the source.

Comment: @powtac We're working under the assumption it is php

Comment: the only way to know is to have access to the source. Otherwise you are out of luck. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`get_included_files()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) into the last PHP line of your footer.php:

```
var_dump(get_included_files());
```

Comment: What if I don't have access to the php files?

Comment: @Ulkmun If you don't have access to the php files, why do you need to know which files a page is made from?

Comment: If it's not your webpage then you are out of luck (unless you email the creator and he tells you :))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_included_files` function for this purpose.

For more info,

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php